# Adding columns and button to column in Openui5 table dynamically

Tags: sapui5

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

    <title>OData Date Table Multiple Sorters</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">

    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" type="text/javascript" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core,sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_goldreflection">
    </script>
    <script>
    var aColumnData = [{
        columnId: "col1"
    }, {
        columnId: "col2"
    }, {
        columnId: "col3"
    }, {
        columnId: "col4"
    }, {
        columnId: "col5"
    }];


    var aData = [{
        col1: "Row 1 col 1",
        col2: "Row 1 col 2",
        col3: "Row 1 col 3",
        col4: "Row 1 col 4",
        col5: "Row 1 col 5"
    }, {
        col1: "Row 2 col 1",
        col2: "Row 2 col 2",
        col3: "Row 2 col 3",
        col4: "Row 2 col 4",
        col5: "Row 2 col 5"
    }];
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

    oModel.setData({
        columns: aColumnData,
        rows: aData
    });

    var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({
        title: "Table column and data binding",
        showNoData : true,  
        columnHeaderHeight : 10,
        visibleRowCount: 7
    });
    oTable.setModel(oModel);
    oTable.bindColumns("/columns", function(index, context) {
         var sColumnId = context.getObject().columnId;
         //alert(sColumnId.);
        return new sap.ui.table.Column({
            id : sColumnId,
            label: sColumnId, 
           // template: sColumnId, 
          template: new sap.ui.commons.Button({
                                text : sColumnId,
                                icon : 
                                     "sap-icon://accept",
                                enabled: true,
                                press: function(e) {

                      }}),
            sortProperty: sColumnId, 
            filterProperty: sColumnId
        });
    });
    oTable.bindRows("/rows");
    oTable.placeAt("content");
    </script>

</head>

<body class="sapUiBody" id="body" role="application">
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Instead of column values as Button text I get the column names. But if I change the template value from button to sColumnId as stated below I get the output correct :

```
template: sColumnId,
```

Here is the link for jsbin: http://jsbin.com/horozew/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign a literal string to the text property of your button.
Instead you have to bind the text property of the button to the model with your sColumnId as binding path:

```
text: { path: sColumnId }
```

See [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yawixinicu/2/edit?html,output).

If assign a string to the template aggregation of the column, the column creates a TextView and binds its text property with the given string as path [in its setter](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.34/src/sap.ui.table/src/sap/ui/table/Column.js#L336).

---

Edit: Some more information as requested in comment.

You have bound the columns of your table to the datasource (the data from `aColumnData` at the model path */columns*). In the function that you give `bindColumns()` as second parameter you create the `Column` objects for your table. The function is called for each item in `aColumnData`. With that you create the template - a `Button` - and bind its value to the model specifying a relative path (relative to */rows*).

Then you bind your rows of the table to the datasource (the data from `aData` at the model path */rows*). For each item in `aData` a row will be created. Each row gets a binding [Context](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Context.html) that points to the corresponding `aData` entry and enables relative paths inside the row.

The template of each column you created before will be cloned for each row. At this point you could access the data of a single cell.

A quite simple way to do that is a formatter function:

```
text: { 
  path: sColumnId, 
  formatter: function(value){ 
    return "Hi " + value ; 
  } 
}
```

---

Edit: Accessing both the value and the column id

Thanks to javascript closures you can do something like this to access both - the sColumnId and the cell value ([jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zusuhusuji/2/edit?html,output)):

```
     template: new sap.ui.commons.Button({
                            text : {path: sColumnId },
                            icon : {path: sColumnId, formatter: function(value) { if (sColumnId === "col2" && value > "Row 2") return "sap-icon://accept"; else return "" } },
                            enabled: true,
                            press: function(e) {

                  }}),
```

Comment: If I want to get the value doing something likethis  `sColumnId.get()` would give me the value `Col1Row1` is it possible to do so.

Comment: `oText = sap.ui.table.TableHelper.createTextView({text: { path: sColumnId }});
alert(oText.getText());` why does something like this do not work.

Comment: That was good but is there any way I can access the value outside the table eg. what I am trying is based upon the value I need to set up an icon to the button so I am trying to send that value as a parameter to another function to do some operation and return a sap-icon . for eg: from the button template ` icon : sap.ui.controller("oui5mvc.tab").statusCheck(sColumnId),` which would do someoperation and return something like this `return "sap-icon://accept";` but the problem is `sColumnId` values are not accessible in that function so that different icons can be set to different buttons.

Comment: And also I have marked the problem is first all text are set and then all icons as when I try `formatter: function(value){ 
  oStorage.put("columnValue",value.toString());  return value ; 
  }` I only get the latest value that has been set to text and the same value is passed each time the function is called from icon.

Comment: Added an other example. Does that help? If you need more processing i would recommend that you process your model right after the data has loaded ([Model.attachRequestCompleted](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Model.html#event:requestCompleted)).